# Django reverse internalization/localization

Tags: python, django, localization, internationalization, timezone

This is quite different question. We have a django web application in an European language. Now we want same app in English language.

I guess if I just follow the django internalization/localization steps in reverse order, I will be able to make the app in English (The original code was written by someone else). But I think this is not an optimal way to do it.Is there any better way or ways?

PS. local timezone will be India for now. We plan to add other countries as well in coming days.

Answer (score 2):

There are two parts to reach your desired solution which you have pointed out: internationalization & localization.

> **internationalization**
>
> Preparing the software for localization. Usually done by developers.
>
> **localization**
>
> Writing the translations and local formats. Usually done by translators.

It's important to note that if the code was not properly structured for localization then the translation will not suffice.

Review the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/) for further information.

Comment: Also, the gettext style internationalization was designed to use English-like language as the source language for ngettext and such. The best option would be to translate to English in source and then internationalize.

Answer (score 0):

Time zones is rather simple to implement. Simply use pytz and/or dateutil. Your question is quite broad, can you give an example of specific language issues you're facing?

Comment: Unfortunately depending on the implementation, timezones are far from simple to implement, thanks to databases not storing timezoned stamps and python datetime being completely botched and not really supporting timezones. This becomes very evident when reading pytz documentation. Especially with server/database local timezone in anything else than UTC you will most certainly have problems.

Comment: Converting to UTC would be one of the first steps, and yes, that may be difficult.

Comment: The problem is that if the timezone uses DST the timestamp can be ambiguous in local timezone. What python does wrong is actually break down the time in datetime at all. Java got it right; the storage of time in java.util.Date is always in UTC seconds, and is only broken down for local timezones for output by java.util.Calendar instances.

Comment: Hey @nicefinly Thanks for answer. I am about to start it, so I thought it would be nice if I could start with best way to do it.